# ASP.NET MVC Show a MessageBox

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a ASP.net MVC application. On one page I have a button and when user clicks on it I need to display some information on a pop up window. How can I do that in ASP.NET MVC? What do I use and where do I write the code for pop window? In the controller? Some java script?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can display messages with javascript. The content of the message can be set in the markup or by your Controller as a Model property. You have a few display options:

- Use the [`alert()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM%3awindow.alert) function, which will display a native browser dialog
- Display a styled modal dialog (E.g. [jQuery UI dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/))
- Display a styled div (E.g. [jQuery UI Message](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-message/) - shameless plug, this one of my open source projects)

The alert function isn't very pretty, but it's the simplest. I typically go with a modal dialog or a styled div, depending on the UI requirements.

Comment: I am going to try the jQuery UI dialog.

Answer (score 0):

If the information you want to display in a pop up is dynamic (i.e you need some c# logic to run) then I'd suggest putting that logic in a controller and have the corresponding view be the pop up itself. You can stick some JavaScript at the top of the view to launch the popup on load.

The page with the button trigger can call that controller and pass any data needed. To make it smooth maybe make the trigger use Ajax.